# Set Location Manager RequestLocationUpdate

Tags: android, xamarin, locationmanager

I am new to Android and Xamarin world. I am trying to create a separate class for Location Manager to be used in different activities. Here is my code

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Locations;


namespace MyLocation
{
 public class LocationManagerActivity 
 {
    private LocationManager _locationManager;
    private Geocoder _geocoder;
    string bestProvider;
    private Context locationContext;

    public LocationManagerActivity (Context lContext)
    {
        locationContext = lContext;
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation()
    {
        string provider = LocationManager.GpsProvider;

        if (_locationManager.IsProviderEnabled (provider)) {

            _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (1000, 100, null, locationContext);
        }
    }

    private void InitializeLocationManager()
    {
        _geocoder = new Geocoder (locationContext);

        _locationManager = (LocationManager)locationContext.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);

        var criteria = new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement };
        bestProvider = _locationManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location lastKnownLocation = _locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        if (lastKnownLocation != null)
        {
            string temp = string.Format("Last known location lat: {0}, long: {1}",
                lastKnownLocation.Latitude, lastKnownLocation.Longitude);

            //string tag = "Last known location: ";

            //Log.Info (tag, temp);
        }

        _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 20, this);

    }
}
}
```

The problem is in the line

```
locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (1000, 100, null, locationContext);
```

Argument 4 has to be Android.App.PendingIntent. How do i set it as the class is not an activity.

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of `RequestLocationUpdates` that takes in a `LocationListener`. See [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)).

So you can have your class implement `ILocationListener` in Xamarin and implement the required methods such as `onLocationChanged` etc. If you're not doing this in an Activity (or something that inherits from `Java.Lang.Object`) you should have your class inherit from `Java.Lang.Object` as it handles the Handle/Disposing for you.

```
public class LocationManagerActivity : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
```

Then you can do this

```
_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 20, this);
```

Comment: Even when i changed the code as you suggested i am getting error at _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates (1000, 100, null, this); Error Argument 4: cannot convert from MyLocation.LocationManagerActivity to Android.App.PendingIntent

Comment: Ignore previous edit. it is working for _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 60000, 20, this);